# How to replace newline for a specific line number?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

Good day to all,

I was wondering how to replace newline at specific line number.

So far I have done: [Linenumber=11]

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;11s/\n//g'
```

Thanks in advance for any clue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through perl,

```
perl -pe 's/\n// if $. == 11' file
```

To save the changes made,

```
perl -i -pe 's/\n// if $. == 11' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file
1
2
3
4
```

---

```
$ perl -pe 's/\n// if $. == 3' file
1
2
34
```

Answer (score 6):

Well if you know the line number then it is pretty straightforward in any language:

```
$ cat file
1
2
3
4
5
```

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed '3{N;s/\n//;}' file
1
2
34
5
```

In `sed`, you can use a number as pattern which will signify the line number. We can enclose action inside braces so that it only takes place when the pattern is true. Here `3` stands for the line 3. Inside the brace is our action which states, `N` to append the next line to pattern space separated by a new line. At this time we have `line 3\nline4` in our pattern space. We follow up with a simple substitution to replace the newline with nothing.

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR==3{printf "%s", $0; next}1' file
1
2
34
5
```

`awk` also comprises of pattern action statements. Here we are using `NR==3` as our pattern. `NR` is `awk` built-in variable which holds the current line number. When the line number is 3 we ask `awk` to do specific action. Our action is inside the braces. We use `printf` which explicitly requires a newline character. `next` allows us to move to the next line. `1` at the end is an `awk` idiom that triggers the default action which is to print. For all lines which do not match our pattern, we print them as is. Since it uses `print` it puts the newline for us.

Using `perl`:

```
$ perl -pe 'chomp if $.==3' file
1
2
34
5
```

With `perl` we use two options. `-p` creates an implicit `while(<>) { print }` loop to process each line of our file. `-e` tells the `perl` interpreter to execute the code that follows it. `$.` in `perl` holds the current line number. `chomp` is a built-in function which removes the trailing newline. So when our line number is 3, we ask `perl` to `chomp` the newline for us. All other lines are printed as is.

Comment: Thanks so much!!! Last question: would it be too much if I ask you how eachone works?